# Winforms c# outlook like Interface

Tags: c#-4.0

I have already asked the same question but in regards with MDI Application design. Now just for R&D purpose so that we can go with 2 solutions to our user. Can somebody plz help me out...

We are developing an OutLook Style Application using C# Winforms. In that application we are using Microsoft Table Control. Which is what we need to show our UI. In the left hand pane we have menu and in the right hand we are displaying our UserControl. Like CustomerManager. This UserControl is doing Adding, Updating, Deleting ect etc but we want to put the common action buttons, Like Add,Delete,Save on the top toolbar.

So far so good, Now what we need to acheve is regardless of UserControl. What ever UserControl is loaded in the MainForm's TableControl. When the save button is clicked it should process the data on that UserControl. Obviously we will write the logic of the Save Action on each UserControl.

Please help...

Regards
Shanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Base user control that contains your Add, Delete, Save methods and events. Then create every other functional control that inherits from the Base control.

When you action the main toolbar buttons, you can safely cast each user control in your given container, to the Base user control.

Some MSDN links you might want to read up on:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44a9ty12(VS.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I may advice you the [Krypton Toolkit](http://www.componentfactory.com/). You will write an Outlook style app in seconds.

Comment: It's an advice. You call it spam.

Comment: friends, I have asked the suggestions, not the components. By the way we are using DevExpress components already. And for this app we will also use DevExpress. For us there is no best component vendor available than Devexpress for Winform application.

Comment: +1 to cancel out the negative vote. This might read like spam but it was a good suggestion (not knowing the OP was using another control set).

Answer (score 1):

For all who ended up here like me in search of a free toolkit: As Vulkanino suggested to use Krypton, I loooked it up.

This is now open source Freeware and can be found unter: [Krypton Toolkit](https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton)